# Does @Value support letting default value reference another @Value？

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
@Value("${test.v1:hello}")
private String testV1;

@Value("${test.v2:${test.v1}}")
private String testV2;
```

When test.v2 is not configured, i want the testV2 is the same with testV1. Does @Value support letting default value reference another @Value？

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing you can do is to define `test.v2=${test.v1}` in your application.properties file. This way, if you override the value for test.v2 through some other ways like environment variables, it will have the defined value, otherwise, it will have the test.v1 value.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use the "+" operand.

```
@Value("${test.v1:hello}")
private String testV1;

@Value("${test.v2:}" + "${test.v1}")
private String testV2;
```

Comment: Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'test.v1' in value "${test.v2:}${test.v1}"

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(testV2) {
        testV2 = testV1;
    }
}
```